# Where to buy/download Commodore-64 games

Tags: backwards-compatibility, commodore-64

Where can I buy/download Commodore-64 games to be run by a Commodore-64 emulator on my PC?

Comment: I like the retro-gaming tag

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about shopping advice (where to buy a game) which is off-topic on Arqade.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[C64.COM](http://www.c64.com/) has more games than you'll have the time for.

Comment: Waaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaoo. Finally I found Turrican my amazing nostalgic game. Thanks man.

Comment: I would have given 2 upvotes, if I could.

Answer (score 2):

[Ebay](http://ebay.com) is always a good place to buy the old cartridges.

And, a simple Google [search](http://www.google.com/search?q=commodore+64+roms) will point you in the right direction for downloading ROMs.

Keep in mind that downloading ROMs is legally dubious, even if you have a hard-copy of the game.  However, this falls under the US definition of Fair Use.